# Doctrine2 user defined DQL return types

Tags: doctrine-orm, boolean, dql

The [DQL user defined functions manual page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html) says:

> There are three types of functions in DQL, those that return a numerical value, those that return a string and those that return a Date.

I find this quite vague. What type to use if function returns a `boolean` value? Is there a more detailed explanation?

Comment: You would use numeric for booleans.  It is a bit limited.  I suppose you could take a look at the code for the config object and see if a boolean type could be added. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html#registering-your-own-dql-functions